# Does Reverse Osmosis remove elemental ions from water?

Tags: osmosis, filtering

From what I understand, RO is able to remove (or at least considerably reduce) the salts dissolved in water.

But thinking about it just doesn't make sense. RO works by filtering the solution using a membrane with pores *so fine that only water can go through them*. But elemental ions are WAY smaller than molecules of water.

So how does RO prevents salts from going to the other side?

Comment: Are you sure those ions are way smaller? Especially if you consider their aqueous layers around them necessary to stabilize their charge?

Comment: Elemental ions are definitely not WAY smaller than molecules of water. Besides, they are charged.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is *pressure*. What you've described above is basically just osmosis, and without applied pressure to overcome the osmotic pressure of the system, reverse osmosis doesn't happen.

[This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_osmosis#Process) Wikipedia article gives a good description of the concept, and the difference between filtration, osmosis and reverse osmosis:

> Osmosis is a natural process. When two solutions with different
>   concentrations of a solute are separated by a semipermeable membrane,
>   the solvent has a tendency to move from low to high solute
>   concentrations for chemical potential equilibration.
>
> Formally, reverse osmosis is the process of forcing a solvent from a
>   region of high solute concentration through a semipermeable membrane
>   to a region of low solute concentration by applying a pressure in
>   excess of the osmotic pressure. The largest and most important
>   application of reverse osmosis is the separation of pure water from
>   seawater and brackish waters; seawater or brackish water is
>   pressurized against one surface of the membrane, causing transport of
>   salt-depleted water across the membrane and emergence of potable
>   drinking water from the low-pressure side.
>
> The membranes used for reverse osmosis have a dense layer in the
>   polymer matrix—either the skin of an asymmetric membrane or an
>   interfacially polymerized layer within a thin-film-composite
>   membrane—where the separation occurs. In most cases, the membrane is
>   designed to allow only water to pass through this dense layer, while
>   preventing the passage of solutes (such as salt ions). This process
>   requires that a high pressure be exerted on the high concentration
>   side of the membrane, usually 2–17 bar (30–250 psi) for fresh and
>   brackish water, and 40–82 bar (600–1200 psi) for seawater, which has
>   around 27 bar (390 psi)[6] natural osmotic pressure that must be
>   overcome.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same question because yes [ions are significantly smaller](https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Physical_and_Theoretical_Chemistry_Textbook_Maps/Supplemental_Modules_(Physical_and_Theoretical_Chemistry)/Atomic_Theory/Sizes_of_Ions) than a molecule of water.

After some research I concluded that the effective size of ion in a solution is actually dictated by the [solvation shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solvation_shell). This arrangement of water molecules around the ion neutralize the charge and make it much larger than an individual water molecule and the pores in the reverse osmosis membrane.